# timer.schedule variable speed

Tags: java

i wan't a timer do a job every 2.5 seconds (at the start of the program),
that is working with the following code.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();


timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

     //   @Override
     @Override
        public void run() {

here is the code, and i do Speed = Speed-500

      }, Speed,Speed);
```

Speed is a int:

```
public int Speed=2500;
```

buth the problem is that the speed of the timer stays on the 2500, while the variable speed lowers each time with 500, so that part is working. Only the timer doesn't check if Speed has changed.

Can somebody help me with this?

Comment: do you have a `speed = speed - 500;` statement in your run method?

Comment: yes i have, if (score==10 ){
            Speed = Speed-500;}

Answer (score 3):

you cant do that because it will fix that with Timer once you done the schedule.

Schedules the specified task for repeated fixed-delay execution, beginning after the specified delay. Subsequent executions take place at approximately regular intervals separated by the specified period.

In this case you can cancel the previous one and schedule new TimerTask.

```
Timer timer = new Timer();

initialize the speed here

loop based on time

timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

     //   @Override
     @Override
        public void run() {

here is the code, and i do Speed = Speed-500

      }, Speed,Speed);
```

Comment: Hello, what do you mean with 'loop based on time'?

Comment: whenever you want to reduce the time, do the task up-to that time then once again assign new task with new reduced time.

Comment: so i should do speed-500, just under the Timer timer = new Timer(); and in the run() function?

Comment: can't get it to work, he only does 1 time speed-500 after that the timer works constantly on 2000. I did speed=speed-500; right under Timer timer = new Timer(); and in my public void run() function